# Filtering the data by Date column using PyRFC with RFC_READ_TABLE

Tags: python, c#, abap, saprfc, pyrfc

I managed to connect to SAP ABAP via Python, using PyRFC and `RFC_READ_TABLE`.

I am trying to figure how to querying a table by a Date column using the parameter `OPTIONS`.

I know the query should be the same syntax as in C# RFC, but I didn't find anything about filter by interval (bigger then / smaller then).

For example in SQL I can use:

```
where date > 2022.3.3
```

Thank you.

Comment: The parameter `OPTIONS` of `RFC_READ_TABLE` takes exactly the same text as in SQL after `WHERE`, except that `OPTIONS` is a table with lines of 72 characters so better define one condition per line. Also, in ABAP-based tables, the dates are stored in format as 8 characters YYYYMMDD (in Gregorian calendar). So a valid value for `OPTIONS` parameter (which also works after SQL `WHERE`) is: `DATE > '20220303'` in line 1, `AND DATE < '20221231'` in line 2, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can put below statement into OPTIONS:

```
DATE GT '20220303'
```

- GE: Greater or equal
- LT: Less then
- LE: Less or equal